# One class different style

Tags: css

how do you apply different styles to one class? I have 3 images and two of them have the same class. I want these 3 images to  stay in one line. I don't know how to do it without the two images in the same class overriding each other. TIA!

```
    .banners {
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     }

    .banner1 {
     display:block;
     width:28%;
     float:left;
     }

    .middlebanner {
     width:28%; float:right;
     }
```

This is what I have tried so far. I have two images in class banner1 and I want these two to be side by side with the middlebanner.

Comment: Please post your code (ideally in a fiddle) with what you have tried so far and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Charles. Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible i guess to apply different styles to one class. Why not using 3 different classnames?

something like this?

```
.class1, .class2, .class3 {
    background-color: #987654;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
}
.class2 {
    background-color: #123456;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/dNm8D/)